# How to change traitlets Dict to a normal python dictionary type?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-traitlets

How to convert traitlets Dict type to normal python dictionary type. I have an example code as given below when I am trying to access the keys and values of `form_output` as a standard python dictionary it shows an error.

```
form_output = Dict().tag(sync=True)
```

How to transform `form_output` to a `dict` type from a `Dict` and access the values.